# Can't launch Flutter application in release mode (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, flutter

I've wanted to launch my Flutter application on Xcode in Release mode (to take screenshot without the debug sign, to uploading them for the Appstore preview). Sadly, something with the Audio package went wrong (worked perfect in debug mode). I'm assuming it's only a small error.

I already tried to start it on a fresh device wihtout data, but no success.

Here's a piece of my terminial output, where you can see the repeating error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc148) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98b8f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioTimeConverter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafce18) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98b940). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class SSRAESKeyManager is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd750) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98b9b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSPlainAudioFileWriter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc0f8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98bb20). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioChunkForTV is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc0a8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98bbc0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioStreamRequest is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc508) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98bd00). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioDecoder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd408) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98be90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSVoiceTriggerEventInfoProvider is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafcf58) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98c4d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioStartStreamOption is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc378) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98c5c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSDispatchGroup is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd7c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98c6b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSUtils is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd6d8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98c8e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSDiagnosticReporter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafcd28) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98c980). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSRemoteControlClient is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc828) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98cc50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSVTUIAudioSessionRecorder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc738) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98ce30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSRemoteRecordClient is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafca08) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98ce80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioZeroFilter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd188) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98d1a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioCircularBuffer is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd138) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98d330). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class SSREnrollmentDataManager is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafd520) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98d3a8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSServerEndpointFeatures is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafcd78) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98d5b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioChunk is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc328) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98d880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioPowerMeter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc3c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98dc90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioRecordDeviceInfo is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc6e8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98e0f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAsset is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc8c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98e190). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSPolicy is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc9b8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98e280). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSAudioRecorder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc878) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98e460). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[4758]: Class CSOSTransaction is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x13eafc698) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x13d98e640). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

2021-02-15 20:13:34.861009+0100 Runner[4758:5797365] Metal API Validation Enabled

2021-02-15 20:13:36.319923+0100 Runner[4758:5809838] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:60067/GxY8CdbyIsg=/

2021-02-15 20:13:39.700409+0100 Runner[4758:5809821] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)

2021-02-15 20:13:39.701139+0100 Runner[4758:5809821] Errors found! Invalidating cache...

2021-02-15 20:13:43.858755+0100 Runner[4758:5809821] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)

2021-02-15 20:13:43.858944+0100 Runner[4758:5809821] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can add ```debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false``` to your ```MaterialApp``` to hide the debug sign

Answer (score 0):

Just add `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` in you `MaterialApp` widget and it will disable the debug banner that it shows every time. This will allow you to run the app in vscode or android studio itself whatever you are using and will not disturb dependencies hopefully

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is it not a problem if the app wont launch in release mode on xcode? I mean it should launch successful I guess.

Comment: You may face issues in xcode while running the app but you can release the app's ipa inside of the IDE. Just go to this website and follow the steps for how to release the app and see if it works for you and let me know https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-release-your-flutter-app-for-ios-and-android/

Comment: Okay it worked for Android Studio on my Windows PC but not for my iOS Emulator on my Mac (also Android Studio and Xcode). Here's the code snipped:

 return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 87, 87, 1),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 87, 87, 1),
      ),

Comment: Really weird that the debug sign won't disappear.

Comment: just try flutter clean and please update your question with your main.dart file as its not really clear with the comment